# C++20 concepts require operator overloading combine with user-define template operator overloading function

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, language-lawyer, c++20

### case 1

Consider the following `concept` which `requires` the `value_type` of a `range` `R` is printable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

template <class R, typename T = std::ranges::range_value_t<R>>
concept printable_range = requires(std::ostream& os, const T& x) { os << x; };
```

It works fine with `std::vector<int>` on different three compliers:

```
static_assert(printable_range<std::vector<int>>);
```

but if I define a template `operator<<` function with any type `x` after `concepts` define:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const auto& x) { return os << x; }
```

GCC and MSVC can pass the following assert but Clang [**fails**](https://godbolt.org/z/qddf9Y):

```
static_assert(printable_range<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>);
```

Which compiler should I trust? It seems like a Clang bug.

### case 2

Weirdly, If I define a custom struct `S` with `operator<<` support before the `concept` `printable_range` define:

```
struct S{};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const S&) { return os; }
```

Same assert fails with MSVC, but GCC still [**accept**](https://godbolt.org/z/Tx8edG) it:

```
static_assert(printable_range<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>);
```

Is it an MSVC bug?

### case3

If I transform the `operator<<` function into a named function `print`, then all the compiler [**fails**](https://godbolt.org/z/4v1z4s) on the second assert. This surprised me since it looks equivalent to case 1, the key points here are the *member function* vs. *free function* or *operator overloading function* vs. *free function*?

```
void print(int x) { std::cout << x; };

template <class R, typename T = std::ranges::range_value_t<R>>
concept printable_range = requires(const T& x) { print(x); };

void print(auto x) { std::cout << x; };

static_assert(printable_range<std::vector<int>>);
static_assert(printable_range<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>); // failed!
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Which compiler should I trust? It seems like a Clang bug.

This is a GCC/MSVC bug. Name lookup for `os << x` will perform argument-dependent lookup to find any other associated `operator<<`s, but the associated namespaces here are just `std`. Your `operator<<` is *not* in `namespace std`, so lookup should not find it, so there should be no viable candidates.

The fact that GCC and MSVC do so is a bug.

The issue with GCC is that its lookup with operators, specifically, just finds more things than it should (see [51577](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51577), thanks T.C.). That's why it can find the `operator<<` but not the `print`.

Really, these are the same example, just with a different name (`print` vs `operator<<`) and they should have the same behavior.

Answer (score 5):

Clang is correct. This is the usual two-phase lookup rule that GCC is known to handle incorrectly for operators (and MSVC is also not exactly known for proper two-phase lookup support, though they are getting better).

Ordinary unqualified lookup for `operator<<` only occurs from the definition context and finds nothing. Argument-dependent lookup can't find the `operator<<` in the global namespace either, since the global namespace is not an associated namespace of `std::vector<int>`.